# skip header in non-rectangular matrix

Tags: matlab, file, matrix, import

I have consecutive .dat files which I want to read and input into a single matrix by concatenating the files vertically. The code I have so far works fine for simple numeric files with only tabs as delimiter.

```
 import=[];
 data=[];
 for i = 1:32
    data1=[import dlmread(sprintf('%d.dat',i))];
    data=vertcat(data, data1); 
    clear data1;
 end
```

and I take the correct output into the data matrix. But my file format is as follows:

```
                              first    second      third 

 0 11/15 08:57:42.000         54         67         82
 1 11/15 09:48:47.010         49         32         31
 ...
```

As you can see I have three delimiters (: \t /) and headers only in the last three columns which are essentially the ones I want to read, that is I want a matrix:

```
 54         67         82
 49         32         31
 ...
```

I tried specifying the delimiters into the dlmwrite and how many rows/columns to skip but an error occurs in sprintf ('delimiter = sprintf(delimiter); % Interpret \t (if necessary)'). Does anyone have any idea how to go about this?

UPDATE:

I managed to get a little further

```
 data=[];
 for i = 1:32
     filename = sprintf( '%d.dat',i );
     data1=importdata(filename);%creates a cell array
     data2=cell2mat(data1(3:end,:));%converts it to char
     %The data, without the header, start from the 3rd row.
     data=vertcat(data, data2); %concatenate vertically all the files     
     clear data1; clear data2;
  end
 %the data
 a1=str2num(data(1:end,20:25));%the first data column is in char 20-25
 a2=str2num(data(1:end,30:35));%the second data column is in char 30-35
```

The thing is that the last part takes too much time, over an hour has passed until I manually stopped it. Does anyone know a simpler and faster way to do this?

Comment: Please provide the actual error message.

Comment: @excaza I already did in my original post: ''delimiter = sprintf(delimiter); % Interpret \t (if necessary)''

Comment: That is not an error message.

Comment: @excaza I'm sorry but this is the error I get:
Error using sprintf
Invalid format.

Error in dlmread (line 71)
    delimiter = sprintf(delimiter); % Interpret \t (if necessary)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this myself so I post it here for future reference:

```
 for i = 1:32
    filename = sprintf( '%d.dat',i );
    data1 = dlmread(filename,'',2,3);%start from row 2, headercolumn 3
    data=vertcat(data, data1);   
    clear data1; 
 end
```

Now the data matrix contains only my data columns and it runs in a few seconds.